# Logic Apps SQL Injection possible?

Tags: security, sql-injection, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app thats taking data from an excel sheet (List rows present in a table) and inserts these values into a TSQL table (Insert row (V2)).

Excel data is created by users.

Is it possible that SQL injection can occur? Could someone put in malicious SQL in excel, which is then executed by the Insert row (V2) logic app component?

If yes, what could be a mitigation?

Thanks

Comment: i would imagine this will use sql parameters so you should not worry that much, you could always audit the generated insert and see hwat s going on under the hood

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box solution to validate if your excel row content has the malicious code or script. You need to have your custom solution to validate the text/content of the excel if it is valid or not before passing it to your Insert row (V2) logic app action.

You can leverage the [inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code?tabs=consumption) to validate the text/content (using regex or expected as per your business need) and if it valid then pass to your Insert rows (v2) action.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Thomas adding your point which may helpful, If the data was not able to meet with the SQL datatype it will not add into table.

#### Steps to avoid adding malicious data

1. **Validate** the data before adding that into database. You can use **[Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action)** action for validate the data.
   Eg: compose Action
   [image]
2. Make use of **Azure Function** for complex validation of the data and ***return that data into Compose action*** and insert into **SQL**.